# How to open the lib/main.dart file

Tags: dart, flutter

So, I've installed Flutter on my iMac, and I'm at the step where says "Open the file lib/main.dart" "Change the string" bla bla bla.

But when I go to lib/main.dart and I try to open it, it says it can't be open and the icon for the file is the same icon used for a .dmg file.

Any idea in how to open that file?

Comment: You can open it on any text editor. How are you trying to open it ?

Answer (score 2):

Right click on main.dart

Press Option, now you can see **Open With** changes to **Always Open With**

Select **Other...**

Choose any Text editor from the list, for example Text Edit

Now you can edit your file...